# How do you resolve a MongoDB 'connection string is not valid' after upgrading?

Tags: upgrade, mongodb, xdb-cloud

On an installation of Sitecore 8.2 update 4, the mongo connection appears to work fine. After upgrading to Sitecore 8.2 update 6 mongo is stating that the connection string is not valid.

> The connection string 'mongodb://username:password@servername.fleet.mongolab.com:port138192/databasename?replicaSet=rs-servername;ssl=true' is not valid.

What may have happened to cause this and how can I get it working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MongoDB driver between the two version changed, which includes a refactoring of the validation for connection strings.

Checking with `MongoDB.Driver.dll` the version details can be seen as the following:

- Sitecore 8.2.4 the MongoDB driver is 1.10.0.62
- Sitecore 8.2.6 the MongoDB driver is 2.4.4.0

Each file uses a regular expression to verify the format of the connection string. I discovered that the password I was provided has a colon `:` in it which needs to be escaped.

> abc:123

The solution here is to encode the colon using `%3A`.

> abc%3A123

Similarly, if you have an `@` symbol you should replace it with `%40`.

**Note:** Only encode the password. The `:` and `@` are also used in the connection string as delimiters which should go untouched.